# Homeomorphism and continuous function between 2 sierpinski spaces

Tags: general-topology

How many homeomorphisms and continuous functions are there between 2 sierpinski spaces? 
Let's say the underlying point set is {0,1}. In my understanding the only way to get both continuous function and homeomorphism is to map 0 → 1 and  1 → 0. Are these 2 distinct cont. functions and homeomorphisms or just 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four maps $\{0,1\} \to \{0,1\}$, namely $\def\id{\mathrm{id}}\id$, the map $c$ that exchanges $0$ and $1$ and finally the constants $\bf 0$ and $\bf 1$. Let's check for each of them whether it is continuous for the Sierpinski topology $\bigl\{\emptyset,\{0\}, S\bigr\}$ on $S := \{0,1\}$ or even a homeomorphism:

(1) $\id$ is trivially continuous, and hence, as it is its own inverse, a homeomorphism.

(2) $c$ is not continuous: To see that, note that $c^{-1}[\{0\}] = \{1\}$, hence the open set $\{0\}$ has a not open inverse image.

(3) The constants are trivially continuous (constants always are), but as they are not invertible, no homeomorphisms.

Conclusion: There are three continuous maps in $S^S$, namely $\id$, $\bf 0$, and $\bf 1$, and $\id$ is the only homeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks a lot, nicely explained!